# Upstart or Cron for neverending python background process in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, upstart

I have a simple little mail queue in Python that I want to run as a neverending background process. I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 and started down the cron route but have been reading some encouragement for upstart. I can't get either to work very well or at all. Any advice?

Comment: what are some of the issues you have with upstart? I've been using upstart to run a python http server that's been working great.

Answer (score 0):

Since your process needs to run forever and doesn't need to be scheduled, you are better of writing an upstart daemon instead of a cronjob. If you Google 'ubuntu upstart deamon' there are plenty of articles with ideas and advice.  For instance, [this one about keeping your deamon alive](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/upstart.html).